# Php Form doesn't sends mysql_query to a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

So my `PHP` Form doesn't sends any information to the database though
there is a connection to the database!I checked everything couple of
times but it still doesn't work.

Any Ideas  where i have a problem in my code? Would be very  appreciative for any help!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>                
            <meta charset="utf-8">        
            <title></title>
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <meta name="description" content="Add your business website description here">
            <meta name="keywords" content="Add your, business, website, keywords, here">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

            <!-- favicon -->  
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

            <!-- google fonts -->
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500,600,700,800,900%7CMerriweather:400,400italic,300,300italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <!-- Font icons -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/elegant-font-icon.css">

            <!-- stylesheet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/bootstrap.css">        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/animate.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/owl.carousel.css">


            <!-- style switcher -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/style-switcher.css">
            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->        
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue.css" title="blue" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/blue-2.css" title="blue-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/purple.css" title="purple" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/green.css" title="green" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/green-2.css" title="green-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/yellow.css" title="yellow" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/orange.css" title="orange" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red.css" title="red" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red-2.css" title="red-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/red-3.css" title="red-3" media="screen"/>        
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/pink.css" title="pink" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/pink-2.css" title="pink-2" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/beige.css" title="beige" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/midnight.css" title="midnight" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colors/black.css" title="black" media="screen"/>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>        
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/html5-3.6-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>    
      <body>


    <div class="row">            
                  <fieldset id="contactform" class="wow bounce" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="0.5s"> 
                 <form action="http://xxxxx.com/forma.php " method="POST">            
                    <div id="form_result"></div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your email">
                      </div>                
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Your Number">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">         
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">                    
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                  </fieldset>
                  </div>



                  </body>
    </html>


    <?php

    $a=mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

    $b=mysql_select_db('xxxxx',$a);

    if (!$b){
    echo 'no connection db ';

    }
    if ($_POST['submit']) {

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO form SET name="'.$_POST['name'].'",email="'.$_POST['email'].'",phone='.$_POST['phone'].',message="'.$_POST['message'].'"');

    } 






    ?>
```

Comment: Your button doesn't have the name 'submit'. $_POST looks at the name of an attribute, not the ID.

Comment: You shouldn't be using obsolete functions

Comment: @StefanValchev he has a `button type` why should he use an `input` ? only the `name="submit"` solves the problem.

Comment: The button submit has had serious problems with IE
Better choice is to use input.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the name attribute. Change:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

To:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="add" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

and give the condition

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO form SET name="'.$_POST['name'].'",email="'.$_POST['email'].'",phone='.$_POST['phone'].',message="'.$_POST['message'].'"');

    }
```

Comment: yyyyyyyeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeehaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa xD =) )))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute **name**.

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" name="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
```

then use

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 mysql_query('INSERT INTO form SET name="'.$_POST['name'].'",email="'.$_POST['email'].'",phone='.$_POST['phone'].',message="'.$_POST['message'].'"');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.